# comparing two text files and output in third file

Tags: python

I have two files on with list of VRM and other which contains images with that name.

This is format :
text file 1:

```
A10KLG
M10SNW
N12TPC
P03GRI
```

TEXT FILE 2 : the strucure of the file DecathlonIN/2015-03-12/;
                                       SmythOUT/2015-03-12/

DecathlonIN/2015-03-12/ - this is in text file 2

inside todays date folder are these images.

```
    A10KLG-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg
    M10SNW-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_11-58-35-162.jpg
    N12TPC-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_14-51-33-152.jpg
    SKLG3-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg
    K10SNW-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg
    ST2TPC-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg

I need to find any any vrm which matches in the third file.

this is my code:

    FILE1 = "file1.txt"
    FILE2 = "file2.txt"
    OUTPUT = "file3.txt"

    with open(FILE1) as inf:
        match = set(line.strip() for line in inf)

    with open(FILE2) as inf, open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
        for line in inf:
            if line.split(' ', 1)[0] in match:
                outf.write(line)-----
```

Like A10KLG is matched in two files it should bring up that in another file...

A10KLG-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg

Comment: So whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Why not `split` on `'-'` instead of `' '`?

Comment: the directory format in searching the files is causing me a problems.. see edited code

Comment: What **precisely** do you mean by *"causing me a problems"*? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Go for the easiest split that's the same between all of your data: `-`.

```
FILE1 = "file1.txt"
FILE2 = "file2.txt"
OUTPUT = "file3.txt"

with open(FILE1) as inf:
    match = set(line.strip() for line in inf)

with open(FILE2) as inf, open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.split('-')[0] in match:
            outf.write(line)
```

file3.txt

> A10KLG-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_10-52-33-152.jpg
>   M10SNW-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_11-58-35-162.jpg
>   N12TPC-GBR_DecathlonIN_2015-03-12_14-51-33-152.jpg